# Como aumentar ou diminuir div proporcional a 720x540?

Tags: html, div

Estou tentando solucionar essa questão pois tenho um slide em .ppt com dimensões de 720w e 540h e minha página é liquida, por isso o motivo de aumentar ou diminuir proporcionalmente.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 8):

A forma mais simples de se criar esse efeito é adicionando o estilo `padding-bottom` com o percentual equivalente da altura dividido pela largura pretendida.

```css
div#slide {
  padding-bottom: 75%; /* 540/720 */
}
```

Assim, mesmo após redimencionar a janela, o tamanho da div será sempre proporcional a 720:540.

Exemplo: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8H62W/).

Comment: +1 Realmente bacana e simples essa solução. Vivendo e aprendendo. :)

Comment: +1 Pelo belo truque, esse eu não conhecia.

Comment: Como dou um min-height nesse caso?

Answer (score 2):

Com um pouquinho de Javascript você pode garantir que o elemento tem a proporção 4:3 fixando uma das dimensões (isto é, ou a largura ou a altura).

Fiz um exemplo (que pode ser testado [nesse JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luigivieira/fxLWp/2/) - basta arrastar a borda do painel *Result* para ajustar as dimensões da exibição) em que a largura do `div` é ajustada à área de exibição da janela do navegador e a altura é calculada com base nessa nova largura e na proporção desejada (`3/4 = 0,75`).

O `div` (que representa o elemento em que você exibe o seu PPT):

```
<div id="teste">
    Olá mundo!
</div>
```

Tem o estilo definido assim (inclui o estilo da "página" de exemplo):

```css
body {
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#teste {
    background-color: red;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 720px;
    height: 540px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 540px;
}
```

E o código `Javascript` que ajusta a proporção é esse:

```js
var adjustSize = function() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("teste");

    var iWidth = window.innerWidth - 10; // Desconta duas vezes o tamanho da borda
    var iHeight = iWidth * 0.75; // Mantém o aspecto 4:3 para a largura (width) fixa

    oDiv.style.width = iWidth.toString() + "px";
    oDiv.style.height = iHeight.toString() + "px";
    oDiv.style.lineHeight = oDiv.style.height;
}

window.onresize = adjustSize;
adjustSize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode determinar as dimensões em porcentagem, sendo assim fica adaptável ao redimensionamento do navegador:

```css
div { width: 80%; height: 80%; border: 1px solid black; }
```

Comment: Ok Igor, ja tentei isso. Só que preciso diminiur ou aumentar proporcionalmente a 720x540 em ratio de 4:3, que ele faca isso tanto se a pessoa diminua ou aumente em width ou height

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um Framework CSS para este fim, como por exemplo o `Twitter Bootstrap`, cujos exemplos você pode encontrar neste link:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

Por exemplo:

```
(...)
<--! inclui o css do twitter-bootstrap, você também pode baixar ele e instalar direto no seu site -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
(...)
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <!-- conteúdo aqui -->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estou usando o bootstrap, só que idéia não é essa, tenho duas div uma do lado esquerdo que é meus menus e outra do lado direito.. a do lado esquerda é fixa. Tenho outra div dentro da do lado direito e essa div deve crescer ou diminuir proporcionalmente ao tamanho de 720x540 conforme a div do lado direito aumente.

Comment: Como tu estás publicando o ppt no site? Copia parte do código que representa teu problema e cola aqui pra gente ver.

Answer (score 0):

Se o seu slide é uma imagem você pode colocar o `img` com `width: 100%` e `height: auto`, ficaria assim:

```css
img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Mas se não for uma imagem, se for, por exemplo, uma `div` que contem uma chamada para um `flash`, você terá que fazer em `js`.

Em jQuery ficaria assim:

Primeiro o `css`.

```css
div { width: 100%; }
```

Depois o `js`, de acordo a proporção indicada, a altura vai ser sempre 75% da largura.

```js
$(function(){

    var largura = $('div').width();
    var altura  = ( 75 * largura ) / 100;

    $('div').css('height', Math.round(altura) + 'px');

});
```

Caso você queira que quando a janela mude de tamanho, a `div` acompanhe, adicione o código abaixo ao js

```js
$( window ).resize(function() {

    var largura = $('div').width();
    var altura  = ( 75 * largura ) / 100;

    $('div').css('height', Math.round(altura) + 'px');

});
```

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t99Lw/), se você redimencionar a janela, verá que aparece a `div` vermelha por trás da preta.