# Bloco div de tamanho proporcional à ele mesmo

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Preciso de um bloco div que tenha tamanho sempre proporcional à ele mesmo, como `width: 100px; e height: 60px;` se width for `200px`, height será `120px`, independentemente do tamanho da tela, e ela deve ter `width: 100%;`

De preferência e se possivel apenas com CSS, mas se precisar de jQuery neh :\
[image: div proporcinal]

Esta imagem ilustra como o bloco deve ser em janelas de tamanhos diferentes e não são vários blocos!

Comment: Por favor, não [apague sua pergunta e reposte](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51142/bloco-div-de-tamanho-proporcional), e sim edite-a para resolver os problemas em potencial (caso haja algum). Mesmo porque eu estava a escrever uma sugestão, quando a pergunta sumiu e eu não pude postar...

Comment: Quem é que define o `width`? Ele é fixo, ou muda via JS, etc? Não há nada que eu saiba no CSS para ajustar uma propriedade em relação a outra, o que você pode fazer é ter uma div externa com um `width` atribuído (por ex. em pixels) e uma div interna com `width: 100%; height: 60%`, isso deve manter a interna proporcional mesmo que você mexa na largura da externa (nota: não testei pra ter certeza).

Comment: Se eu respondesse colando aqui, isto seria cópia. Estou deixando o link de um tópico muito semelhante a este seu, aqui do Stack. Dê uma olhada na resposta do <b>Luiz Vieira</b> e veja se te ajuda. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3485/como-aumentar-ou-diminuir-div-proporcional-a-720x540 A resposta do <b>Guilherme Bernal</b> também no tópico acima pode lhe ajudar, porém causar mais problemas.

Comment: Complementando o que o @mgibsonbr disse, parece haver um consenso entre quem está começando no site que uma pergunta fechada é definitivo. Deve-se encarar uma pergunta fechada como suspensa até que seja melhorada. É uma ferramenta do site que é usada para esse fim, é só ficar tranquilo, ouvir as sugestões e editar a pergunta. ;)

Answer (score 1):

amigo, você pode usar um trick, utilizando tamanhos proporcionais a fonte.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="font-normal">
        Auto
    </div>        
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    font-size: 200px;
    width: 1em;
    height: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.font-normal {
    font-size: medium;
}
```

A medida `em` é relativa ao tamanho da font, então se o `font-size` é 200px, `1em` será `200px` (1 * 200) e `0.5em` será `100px` (0.5 * 200).

Em todo caso será necessario resetar o tamanho da Fonte dentro da `DIV`, por isto tenho uma div interna com `font-size: medium`, que por sinal é o valor default desta propriedade.

Answer (score 0):

Dá pra fazer com porcentagem usando o `padding`.

```css
.content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Clique em **EXECUTAR**, depois em **Página Toda** e vai redimensionando a tela para ver o resultado.