# Como detectar mudanças de mais de 15px no Resize na Janela

Tags: javascript, eventos

Preciso disparar um evento (alert) sempre que uma janela for redimensionada, mas só quando a diferença passar de 15 pixels (para menos ou para mais).

Qual a maneira mais simples de calcular esses 15px?

Comment: Relacionados: [esse](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37856/jquery-unbind-a-tudo-quando-tamanho-da-window-800)  e [esse](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3485/como-aumentar-ou-diminuir-div-proporcional-a-720x540). De uma olhada se já não ajuda.

Comment: O evento de resize da janela eu sei fazer, minha dúvida é em relação a contagem de 15 em 15 pixel pra assim, eu disparar outro evento.

Comment: A altura e largura tem que mudar 15px?

Comment: Como assim? Enquanto você redimensiona a janela, já são disparados vários eventos de resize pelo próprio browser.

Comment: Lucas, pra exemplificar eu preciso que a cada 15 pixel de resize da janela (pra menos) eu possa disparar um evento, por exemplo um alert na página.

Comment: Sim, o que eu quis dizer é que dá para aumentar/diminuir só a altura ou só a largura, ou os 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente, você quer que algo aconteça a cada 15 pixels de resize. Como durante o redimensionamento da janela o evento `resize` ocorre várias vezes, você precisa criar "marcos" em que guarda as dimensões anteriores da janela, e comparar o valor atual com esses marcos. Algo assim:

```
var ultimaLargura = window.innerWidth, 
    ultimaAltura = window.innerHeight;

window.onresize = function() {
    var diffLargura = Math.abs(ultimaLargura - window.innerWidth);
    var diffAltura = Math.abs(ultimaAltura - window.innerHeight);
    if(diffLargura >= 15 || diffAltura >= 15) {
        console.log('executando');   
        ultimaLargura = window.innerWidth;
        ultimaAltura = window.innerHeight;
    }
};
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/zc8dsj46/</sup>

Comment: bfavaretto, era isso mesmo! muito obrigada!

Comment: A outra parte que você tinha comentado você resolveu? Eu estava tentando entender, mas não consegui.

Comment: Ah eu me confundi, deu certinho mesmo. Valeu! ;)